# Circular Suffix Array Creation

Tags: java, sorting

For a homework problem, we are given a String of length n, and we're told to create the sorted suffixs and sort them in such a way that we can return the string corresponding to the original index of the ith index in the sorted list.  For example, given the string "bears", we have as follows:

![image: Commercial Photography]

In other words, a final_index[i] value of 2 means that the suffix originally at index 2 is at index i in the sorted list.

My problem is that the obvious solution, to use substring and build the sorted_suffixes and then to sort those isn't allowed because we're not allowed to explicitly build the suffixes.  How can this limitation be overcome?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use comparator to sort the suffixes with invoking 
public static  void sort(T[] a, Comparator c);

Convert string to  char array

In comparator define compare such that it sorts suffixes lexicographically scanning one character at a time...
You dont need to store suffixes explicitly....

Use all wrapper classes instead of raw classes